# Showing Only Shared Drive and Folders in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I have written the following code which can show the shared folder based UNC path in QTreeView widget. However, QTreeView shows a shared folder with my local drive contents. I wanted to remove local drive from that representation. How should I do that?

```
void MainWindow::ListDirectory(QString arg_smb_path)
{
    o_directorySystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_directorySystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Hidden);
    o_directorySystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->treeView->setModel(o_directorySystemModel);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);


    o_fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_fileSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden);
    o_fileSystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->listView->setModel(o_fileSystemModel);
    ui->listView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
}
```

How should I fix this issue in my program? I wanted only show shared drives and folders in QTreeView with by using UNC/CIFS of windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a `QSortProxyFilterModel` as an intermediate between filesystem model and the tree view.

E.g. like this:

```
class FilterSharedFoldersModel : QSortFilterProxyModel {
protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
};
```

Now in the implementation of `filterAcceptsRow()`, check the type of the respective path and return true or false respectively. See the [method documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) as well as the [example tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html).

The wiring is rather easy:

```
o_directorySystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
o_directorySystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Hidden);
o_directorySystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);
o_directoryFilterModel = new FilterSharedFoldersModel();
o_directoryFilterModel->setSourceModel(o_directorySystemModel);
ui->treeView->setModel(o_directoryFilterModel);
```

Comment: It says, setSourceModel is private memebr. How should I fix it?

Comment: It's not private. `sourceModel` is a regular QObject property. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#setSourceModel